# Browser-Script für Interface-Übersetzung / Browser-Script for interface translation

Tags: discussion, language

See [Help translate the StackExchange UI (Unofficial)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105169/help-translate-the-stackexchange-ui-unofficial) (and my upcoming edit or answer there) for the English version - I'll not translate all my text here to english, as it is mostly the same as there.

---

Wir (zur Zeit [Ninefingers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142852/ninefingers), [Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles) und [Paŭlo Ebermann](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156902/paulo-ebermann)) haben ein Projekt für ein User-Script für die Übersetzung der Stack-Exchange-Nutzer-Oberfläche in beliebige Sprachen. Zuerst sind Französisch und Deutsch auf der Liste, weil das die Sprachen sind, in denen "Language & Usage" Sites existieren, und die wir sprechen.

Ein Prototyp mit deutscher Übersetzung ist jetzt fertig, und kann ausprobiert werden.

Ich habe ihn mit Firefox 3.6.20 (und GreaseMonkey 0.9.10) sowie mit Opera 11.51 ausprobiert, es scheint zu funktionieren. Andere Browser mit UserScript-support habe ich nicht ausprobiert, ich bitte um Rückmeldung.

### Installation

Zur Zeit sind braucht ihr zwei Skripte:

- Ein Wörterbuch ([de](https://raw.github.com/ninefingers/so-translation/master/dictionary-de.user.js), [fr](https://raw.github.com/ninefingers/so-translation/master/dictionary-fr.user.js))
- Das eigentliche [Übersetzungs-Programm](https://raw.github.com/ninefingers/so-translation/master/stack_overflow_translation.user.js)

Mit Firefox + [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) solltet ihr die einfach durch Anklicken installieren können. In Opera müsst ihr sie herunterladen und in ein Verzeichnis stecken, welches ihr dann als UserScript-Verzeichnis definiert. Keine Ahnung, ob/wie das mit anderen Browsern geht.

### Was fehlt noch, wie kann ich helfen?

Es sind auch mit dem Skript nicht alle Elemente der Seiten übersetzt.
Einige haben wir einfach übersehen (bitte weist uns darauf hin), andere sind etwas komplizierter, etwa ist alles, was auf diesem Bild zu sehen ist, ein Bild, kein Text:

[sprite-sheet http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchy/img/sprites-beta.png?v=2](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchy/img/sprites-beta.png?v=2)

Für die Meta-Seiten gibt es ein äquivalentes Bild:

[sprite-sheet http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchymeta/img/sprites-beta.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Skins/sketchymeta/img/sprites-beta.png)

Wer Ideen hat, wie man das löst, melde sich bei uns, z.B. im [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1289/localization-and-translation).

Auch bei den deutschen Übersetzungen bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob die so optimal sind, die habe ich in etwa einer halben Stunde heruntergeschrieben, um zu testen, ob ich wirklich alle französischen Texte aus dem Übersetzungsskript ins Wörterbuch verschoben habe.
Bessere Vorschläge sind willkommen, gerne hier als Antwort. (Am liebsten einfach als geändertes Wörterbuch, aber ich nehme auch Frei-Text-Hinweise.)

An einigen Stellen geht durch das Übersetzen Funktionalität verloren, das sind Bugs. Meldet sie uns. (Und an einigen Stellen geht die Unterscheidung zwischen "Antwort" und "Frage" verloren, so heißt "Post your Question" jetzt "Sende deine Antwort".)

Und wenn unter euch Programmierer sind, die sind natürlich eingeladen, unser JavaScript zu verbessern.

Comment: Related questions: [How can we help with localization; shall we help?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-can-we-help-with-localization-shall-we-help), [Interface localization to German](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/33/interface-localization-to-german)

Comment: @userunknown Thanks for the note. Looks like (a) Github changed their URL schemes, and (b) Ninefingers changed his github account name, both of which make the links don't work anymore. I'll try to correct this.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Are we going to have buttons in German?

Comment: @Alenanno: I didn't work on this project for some months, and I think Ninefingers didn't, too. In principle everything is translateable, one just has to adapt the script to do the right thing, and supply the right translations to it.

Answer (score -1):

Ich schicke gerne das von mir modifizierte js, aber glaube es ist sinnvoller, die Übersetzungsvorschläge erst zur Diskussion zu stellen.

Zum Abstimmen wäre zwar eine Frage pro Ausdruck am günstigsten, aber 20 Fragen dafür zu eröffnen erscheint mir doch falsch. Vielleicht findet der Großteil ja Zustimmung en bloc, und Einzelfälle, die mit 2 Kommentaren nicht erledigt sind, können separat verhandelt werden.

Ich will meine Änderungen kurz begründen. Hier ein Diff:

```
-            "#nav-unanswered" : "Unbeantwortet",
+            "#nav-unanswered" : "unbeantwortet",
```

Das englische Original ist schon nicht immer einheitlich. Mal ist das erste Wort groß, mal keins, mal alle. Ergonomisch lassen sich Wörter leichter erfassen, wenn sie so geschrieben sind, wie sie benutzt werden, also Verben und Adjektive klein, Substantive groß. Insbesondere könnte es relevant sein, falls man sich aus Gründen der Kürze doch für `tags` entscheidet - `tags drauf hatte ich Kopfschmerzen` -

```
-            "#nav-tags" : "Tags",
-            "#h-interesting-tags" : "Lieblings-Tags",
+            "#nav-tags" : "Schlüsselwörter",
+            "#h-interesting-tags" : "Lieblingsschlüsselwörter",
```

`Schlüsselwörter` ist leider etwas lang, `Suchworte` eine Spur kürzer, `Schlagworte` eine weitere Option, manchmal geht auch "Index", etwa für die Seite mit allen Schlagworten.

Verbindungen im Deutschen werden selten mit Bindestrich gebildet - bei Hybriden aus mehreren Sprachen wie dem Back-Shop, oder missverständnisträchtigen Worten wie Ur-Instinkt. Im Regelfall aber einfach aneinanderhängen.

```
-            "#h-top-questions": "Spitzen-Fragen", // ???
+            "#h-top-questions": "Spitzenfragen", // ???

-            "Tags" : "Tags", 
-            "tools" : "Tools",
+            "Tags" : "Schlüsselwörter", 
+            "tools" : "Werkzeuge",

-            "interesting" : "Interessant",
+            "interesting" : "interessant",

-            "hot" : "Angesagt",
-            "not yet" : "Noch nicht",
+            "hot" : "angesagt",
+            "not yet" : "noch nicht",
```

Ich muss noch suchen, wo dieses 'not yet/ noch nicht' vorkommt, ob vielleicht `offen` besser passt.

```
-            "tag subscriptions" : "Tag-Filter",
-            "Add" : "Hinzufügen", // zu lang :-/
-            "_bottom-notice_": "Suchst du mehr?  Sieh die <a href=\"/questions\">Gesamt-Liste der Fragen</a>, oder <a href=\"/tags\">Tags</a>. Hilf mit, <a href=\"/unanswered\">unbeantwortete Fragen</a> zu beantworten.",
+            "tag subscriptions" : "Schlüsselwortfilter",
+            "Add" : "zufügen", // immer noch zu lang? wo kann ich das prüfen/sehen? 
+            "_bottom-notice_": "Suchst du mehr?  Sieh die <a href=\"/questions\">Gesamtliste der Fragen</a>, oder <a href=\"/tags\">Schlüsselwörter</a>. Hilf mit, <a href=\"/unanswered\">unbeantwortete Fragen</a> zu beantworten.",

-            "one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer" : "eine der Antworten wurde akzeptiert",
+            "one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer" : "eine der Antworten wurde angenommen",
```

`angenommen` klingt für mich eine Spur weicher, wärmer als das formalere `akzeptiert`, aber es macht keinen gr. Unterschied.

```
-            "add comment" : "Kommentieren",
+            "add comment" : "kommentieren",

-            "This answer is useful (click again to undo)" : "Diese Antwort ist nützlich (noch einmal klicken für rückgängig)",
-            "This answer is not useful (click again to undo)" : "Diese Antwort ist nicht nützlich (noch einmal klicken für rückgängig)",
+            "This answer is useful (click again to undo)" : "Diese Antwort ist nützlich (zum Widerrufen noch einmal klicken)",
+            "This answer is not useful (click again to undo)" : "Diese Antwort ist nicht nützlich (zum Widerrufen noch einmal klicken)",
```

`Klicken für rückgängig` geht gar nicht. :) Das ist wie `Schlafen für munter`.

```
-            "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)" : "Diese Frage zeigt Recherche-Aufwand, sie ist nützlich und klar  (noch einmal klicken für rückgängig)",
-            "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)" : "Diese Frage zeigt keinen Recherche-Aufwand, sie ist unnütz oder unklar (noch einmal klicken für rückgängig)",
+            "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)" : "Diese Frage zeigt eigenen Rechercheaufwand, sie ist nützlich und klar (zum Widerrufen noch einmal klicken)",
+            "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)" : "Diese Frage zeigt keine Vorleistung an Recherche, sie ist unnütz oder unklar (zum Widerrufen noch einmal klicken)",
```

Ob `Vorleistung an Recherche` oder `eigenen Rechercheaufwand` - ich finde beide Formulierungen etwa gleich gut, aber nicht eine für hier, die andere für da besser, sondern wollte nur beide zur Diskussion stellen, da ich keine klare Vorliebe habe.

So oder so ist der Bindestrich in Rechercheaufwand falsch.

```
-            "This is a favorite question (click again to undo)" : "Dies ist eine Lieblings-Frage (noch einmal klicken für rückgängig)",
-            "View upvote and downvote totals" : "Sieh die Zahlen der hoch- und nieder-Stimmen", // ?? http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/998/
+            "This is a favorite question (click again to undo)" : "Dies ist eine Lieblingsfrage (zum Widerrufen noch einmal klicken)",
+            "View upvote and downvote totals" : "Summe der Plus- und Minusstimmen ansehen", // ?? http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/998/
```

"Dies ist eine Lieblingsfrage" ist vielleicht besser mit

- "Diese Frage beobachten" beschrieben, oder
- "Veränderungen bei diesem Thema beobachten"
- "Frage abonnieren"

[The script in full on github](https://gist.github.com/1748823)

Comment: Please, replace the parts that are not the buttons themselves with English.

Comment: Without German knowledge you can not participate at this discussion, I guess.